# py2neo expand graph by accessing nodes from execute() record

Tags: neo4j, cypher, record, py2neo

As I have learnt from another question it is apparently not possible in Cypher alone to copy a subgraph or to duplicate a chain of nodes. But I need to do this somehow. Therefor I looked for a more hacky approach to do this.

Specifically I need to transform am graph that looks like this:

```
(A)──>(N1:T1)──>(B)
```

into a graph that looks like this

```
(A)──>(N1:T1)──>(B)
 │               ^
 └───>(N2:T2)────┘
```

Though the part between `A` and `B` can be arbitrarily long. What matters is that all nodes of type `T1` get converted to type `T2` in the *copy* of the original path (the one with `N1` in the example).

So, if I have for example this graph:

```
MERGE (N1:A)-[:r]->(N2:B)-[:r]->(N3:C)
MERGE (N1)-[:r]->(N4:C)-[:r]->(N5:C)
```

and a query that looks like this:

```
MATCH p=(:A)-[*0..]->(:B)-[*0..]->(:C)
RETURN p
```

and I execute it with `graph.cypher.execute(<query>)` then the record returned by `execute()` is:

```
   | p                         
---+----------------------------
 1 | (:A)-[:r]->(:B)-[:r]->(:C)
```

Now I would like to get the IDs of all the nodes. Then I could generate a string with Cypher code that represents the copied path and execute it again with `execute()`. And in that string I would use the IDs of nodes in the record to connect to the existing nodes in the database. But I recall that it is somehow not possible either, to target nodes in the database from outside via an ID... or is in fact it possible? Are there any other ways I could go about this? Somebody mentioned the `dump` functionality, but the documentation is very lacking on that and I don't quite understand how it is supposed to work. And in addition I am not even sure if it does what I need.

Comment: Do *all* the nodes between the `:A` and `:C` have the `:B` label?

Comment: Also, it is possible for you to use a node's `ID` (and it will remain unique as long as the node is not deleted).

Comment: No, only some of the nodes between the `:A`-nodes and the `:C`-nodes have label `:B` (or label `:T1` respectively, if we go with the second example). How can I however get the IDs of the nodes in the chain of the record?

Comment: You can use the [ID()](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-id) function to get the neo4j-generated ID for any node or relationship. That ID is guaranteed to be unique for the lifetime of that node/relationship, but can be reused after it is deleted.